# Elisp upcase match in replace-regexp-in-string

Tags: elisp

I'm wanting to extract the content from LaTeX markup, modify the content, and then copy it to the clipboard. Specifically, I want to pull everything inside a `\textsc{}` environment and change it to uppercase. This would take something like `\textsc{3sg.hum}` and output `3SG.HUM`. The function I've written so far will remove the markup, but will not capitalize its contents, so when I run my function on `\textsc{3sg.hum}`, it outputs `3sg.hum`.

This is the code I've written so far. As of now, I'm just writing the output to the message buffer and I'll handle the clipboard stuff later.

```
(defun reformat-latex-gloss (beginning end)
  "Strip LaTeX environments, converting small caps to uppercase"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (let* ((gloss (buffer-substring beginning end))
             (replacement
              (replace-regexp-in-string
               "\\\\textsc{\\(.*?\\)}"
               (upcase "\\1")
               gloss
               nil)))
        (message "%s" replacement))
    ""
    )
  )
```

When I run this function on something like `\textsc{3sg.h}`, it outputs `3sg.h` rather than the expected `3SG.H`. It seems like there's a problem with the line `(upcase "\\1")`; if I replace `\\1` with a string like `test`, the output will be uppercase `TEST`, so it seems like `upcase` is not applying to the numbered match as I would have expected.

I haven't had any luck finding solutions for this problem. Many of the resources like [this](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/06/shiny-and-new-emacs-22.html) show how to do this sort of thing in the interactive mode, but I'm wanting to run this non-interactively. I'm still very new to Elisp, so I'm likely overlooking something simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a solution. I needed to wrap the replacement in a lambda expression and call `match-string`, so the functioning code is

```
(defun reformat-latex-gloss (beginning end)
  "Strip LaTeX environments, converting small caps to uppercase"
  (interactive "r")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (let* ((gloss (buffer-substring beginning end))
             (replacement
              (replace-regexp-in-string
               "\\\\textsc{\\(.*?\\)}"
               (lambda (match)
                 (upcase (match-string 1 match)))
               gloss)))
        (message "%s" replacement))
    ""
    )
  )
```